# How to exclude certain chunk from index.html in React (Create React App)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension, create-react-app

I'm building a chrome extension with create-react-app.

I have the following config-overrides.js

```
const { override } = require('customize-cra');

const overrideEntry = (config) => {
  config.entry = {
    main: './src/popup', // the extension UI
    background: './src/background',
    content: './src/content',
  };

  return config;
};

const overrideOutput = (config) => {
  config.output = {
    ...config.output,
    filename: 'static/js/[name].js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].js',
  };


  return config;
};

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => override(overrideEntry, overrideOutput)(config),
};
```

The project contains 3 parts : the popup (main), the content-script (content) and the service-worker (background).

However the generated index.html (after build) of my popup includes a script tag which includes *background* and *content*.

But I'd like these two files not to be included in my index.html. So a potential solution will be to remove manually from the index.html in the build repository but I'm looking for for a better way of doing this.

Any ideas ?